# How to use the mat-icon in MatSnackBar?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to display an icon when displaying a message from the service message service which uses `MatSnackBar`. (The Material module is imported in the app's module).

However, the default snackbar doesn't support an icon. How do I implement such a feature?

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition, MatSnackBarVerticalPosition} from "@angular/material";


@Injectable()

export class MessagesService {
    horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'right';
    verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top';

    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    }

    info(message: string) {
        const icon = `<mat-icon>info</mat-icon>`;
        const msg = `${icon} ${message}`;
        this.snackBar.open(msg, 'X', {
            duration: 2000,
            horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,
            verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,
            panelClass: ['info-message']
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use a custom snackbar component in order to show the icon. Thankfully, this should be similar to how you would define a dialog to show content, just that it's a snackbar instead of a dialog.

It's possible to pass in data to a snackbar, the same way as passing data to a dialog.

Note that when declaring a snackbar, you also have to import it in the `entryComponents` property in the `NgModule` declaration.

Here's an example:

`icon-snack-bar.component.ts`

```ts
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
// ...

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `<mat-icon>{{ data?.icon }}</mat-icon> <span>{{ data?.message }}</span>`
  // Most likely you have to add styles in order to position the icon, although I haven't tested it yet
export class IconSnackBarComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

`my-component.component.ts`

```ts
import { IconSnackBarComponent } from './icon-snack-bar/icon-snack-bar.component';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
// ...

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }
  openCustomSnackBar() {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(IconSnackBarComponent, {
      data: {
        message: 'Hello, snackbar!',
        icon: 'info'
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IconSnackBarComponent } from './icon-snack-bar/icon-snack-bar.component';
// ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
    IconSnackBarComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    IconSnackBarComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is also partially covered in the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#sharing-data-with-a-custom-snack-bar).

Comment: Cant this be done with unicode without creating new component ? Just curious thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by Edric.

If using flex layout, you dont need additional styles to align your snackbar content. Just wrap content in a div with proper layoutAlign values.

Comment: You should comment instead.

Comment: Sorry. I need reputation to comment and i just came across this problem while working on something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved with pure CSS.
Add your snackbar-code with action in your component.
In this example the text "close" will be rendered as a close image with the X symbol. Other Text like "delete" will render a trash basket.

```
this._snackBar.open('your snack bar message', 'close');
```

Add the following CSS. Make sure you have the Google Icon Font properly imported.

```
.mat-simple-snackbar .mat-button-wrapper {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: none;
}
```

More about icons you find here: [enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview)

Comment: this save my day.